# fromMap is assigning null values from json reponse

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I am trying to assign JSON response dart Entity using fromJson but the return object is having all null values.

**The json looks like below:**

```
{
   "doc":{
      "id":"6496772",
      "name":"Test Document",
      }
      "custom_keys":[
        {
        "key": "X1",
        "name":"X1"
        },
        {
        "key": "X2",
        "name":"X2"
        },
      ]    
}
```

**I have created Test Entity as below**

```
class Test{
  final String id;
  final String name;

  const Feature({
    this.id,
    this.name,
  });

  Feature.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>  map) :
    id= map['id'],
    name= map['name'];
```

}

**API method:**

```
var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
      var response = await request.close();

      if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {
        var json = await response.transform(UTF8.decoder).join();
        print(json.toString());
        var data = JSON.decode(json);

        return new Test.fromMap(data['doc']);
```

// getting null object from above return statement
There is error message. what could be the issue ?

Comment: do you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the null object probably comes from `id= map['id'],` while your json only returns "key" and "name".

you have to map each json element to a property. changing the constructor to

```
Feature.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>  map) :
    id= map['key'],
    name= map['name'];
```

will probably do the trick.